# Execute commands inside subshell from script

Tags: cmd

In order to retrieve my Android app's database from device, I execute this commands:

```
prompt1> adb shell
prompt2> run-as my.app.package
prompt3> chmod -R 777 databases
prompt3> exit
prompt2> cat /data/data/my.app.package/databases/database.db > /sdcard/database.db
prompt2> exit
prompt1> adb pull /sdcard/database.db
```

I want automate this process so I have created a script with those commands. Problem is that when I execute it, `adb shell` is opened and the next commands are not executed.

Note that `run-as my.app.package` opens another third shell.

**EDIT**

When I execute the script:

```
prompt1> get_database.cmd
prompt2> _
```

It opens prompt2, but it stops.

How can I do it?

Comment: Actually, `run-as` open a third shell

Comment: Your examples are somewhat confusing. Are you searching for a solution in a UNIX-like shell (say `sh`, `csh`, etc.) or for Windows' `CMD`?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I need a CMD solution.

Comment: Then I would suggest, you rework your question (examples). The first one sports a whole slew of UNIXish commands (cat, chmod, etc.) can lead to the impression that you're actually looking for sh.

Comment: I have them installed in my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved it this way:

```
@echo off
IF "%1" == "" goto USAGE
IF "%2" == "" goto USAGE

adb shell "run-as %1 chmod -R 777 /data/data/%1/databases; cat /data/data/%1/databases/%2 > /sdcard/%2"
adb pull /sdcard/%2
goto END

:USAGE
@echo Usage: %0  ^<package^> ^<file_name^>

:END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the commands to the shell with quotes:

```
adb shell "
adb run-as my.app.package 'chmod -R 777 databases; exit'
cat /data/data/my.app.package/databases/database.db > /sdcard/database.db
exit
"
adb pull /sdcard/database.db
```

Comment: Can you add some details? The single quote ``'...'`` can be replaced by an external file ``adb run-as my.app.package < script.adb`` with ``chmod -R 777 databases; exit`` inside script.adb